# select columns in a dataframe via indexing notation and not column names

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a `df_D` from the given input `df` using the entry 'Start' as my reference for both the row and column indexing.

I do not want to use the column names `A,B, C` etc.

Instead, I wish to use indexing as the sequence is always the first 3 columns from 'START' and the last 3 columns, ie something like `n,n+1,n+2, n+5,n+6,n+7`

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['jfgh',23,'Ndfg',34,0,56],'B':['jfgh',23,'START',34,0,56], 'C':['cvb',7,'dsfgA',65,47,3],'D':['rrb',7,'gfd',3,0,7],'E':['dfg',7,'gfd',5,12,1],'F':['dfg',7,'sdfA',5,0,4],'G':['dfg',7,'sdA',5,8,9],'H':['dfg',7,'gfA',5,0,8],'I':['dfg',7,'sdfA',5,7,23]})
```

Output:

```
      A      B      C    D    E     F    G    H     I
0  jfgh   jfgh    cvb  rrb  dfg   dfg  dfg  dfg   dfg
1    23     23      7    7    7     7    7    7     7
2  Ndfg  START  dsfgA  gfd  gfd  sdfA  sdA  gfA  sdfA
3    34     34     65    3    5     5    5    5     5
4     0      0     47    0   12     0    8    0     7
5    56     56      3    7    1     4    9    8    23
```

Desired Output: df_D Created manually

```
    B   C  D  G  H   I
0   0  47  0  8  0   7
1  56   3  7  9  8  23
```

Attempt 1:

```
for index in range(len(df)):
    if str(df.loc[index,'C']).startswith('START'):
        df_D = df.iloc[index+1:len(df), [1,2,3,6,7,8]]
        break
```

Resulting Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [B, C, D, G, H, I]
Index: []
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Why did you only select the last two rows?

Comment: I only want data from columns B,C,D,G,H and only the last 2 rows as shown in `df_D`

Comment: so you want to slice from start onwards and a select number of columns?

Comment: correct but not using column names only some  n+1 indexing or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 0 : Initialize an empty list k

Step 1 : Iterate through all the columns using for loop on df.shape[1] "START"

Step 2 : Iterate through all rows in each column i did this using df. shape[0]

Step 3: search for "START"

Step 4: once found store the column no. and row number in variables.

Step 5: use those variables to index all rows and columns you want. so you use row+1 since you want everything below START and col ,col+ 1 so on.

step 6: add the dataframe to the list k

final step : you can see k[0] gives first instance of start, k[1] giving second instance of start, you can use this as more general code.
If you don't want all instances use break as soon as first dataframe is found.

```
k=[]
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for y in range(df.shape[0]):
        if df.iloc[y,i] == 'START':
            col = i
            row = y
            k.append(df.iloc[row+1:,[col,col+1,col+2,-3,-2,-1]])    
print("first START")
print(k[0])
print("\n Second START")
print(k[1])
```

Comment: Similar to my comment  @Physmatik, how would I generalise the indexing of the rows? I also tried `df.iloc[[i, len(df)], [idx, idx+1, idx+2, idx+5, idx+6, idx+7]]`

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by generalize ? You need last N rows ? then replace the last line with this

`df.iloc[[-n:],[idx,idx+1,idx+2,-3,-2,-1]]`

is this what you were looking for ? how do you want to define logic for no of rows ?

Comment: I want the logic to be such that the number of rows is equal to the length of the column from the 'START' position to the end of the column. So in this case the resulting logic should be 2

Comment: @user9106985 ; understood I have edited my answer to help you generalize the code. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: this works a beauty and thanks!!!!.... but there 1 caveat that I discovered only after running your solution. I dont think I can edit the original post but the dataframe `df` has 2 instances of 'START' as shown below. It seems your code performs the calculation on the last instance of 'START'. I would like the code to run on the first instance.

Comment: `df= pd.DataFrame({'A':['jfgh',23,'Ndfg',34,0,56],'B':['jfgh',23,'START',34,0,56], 'C':['cvb',7,'dsfgA',65,47,3],'D':['rrb',7,'gfd',3,0,7],'E':['dfg',7,'gfd',5,12,1],'F':['dfg',7,'START',5,0,4],'G':['dfg',7,'sdA',5,8,9],'H':['dfg',7,'gfA',5,0,8],'I':['dfg',7,'sdfA',5,7,23]})`

Comment: @user9106985 : In that case i have initialized a list to store every instance of start to make the program even more generic, now you can use k[0] to get your answer and k[1] to find data frame for next instance of START.
I have edited the code above. Check it out and see if that is what you wanted, if yes please accept it as an answer.

Comment: That works very well @Bharath. Thanks for introducing me to new programming ideas.

Comment: Anytime @user9106985, wish you god speed in your programming skills.

Comment: sorry to bother you again! I was examining the break function and some how I get the same output as condition with no break. I placed 'break' directly under the line starting with k.append. I expect k[1] not to be available if the break function is used...

Comment: Thats because the break is breaking inner loop only and outer for loop still runs. try below logic. 
```
var = 0 
for ( outer loop ) :
        for (inner loop ):  
               if ( condition):
                   do this and this
                   set var = 1
                   break 
           if var ==1
           break.
``` 

Let me know if its not clear - i will explain in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `np.where` to find the start index. Then use `iloc` with `np._r` to create our slices:

```
start_col = np.where(df.eq("START"))[1][0]
cols = df.shape[1]
col_select = np.r_[start_col: start_col+3, cols-3: cols]

df.iloc[-2:, col_select]
```

```
    B   C  D  G  H   I
4   0  47  0  8  0   7
5  56   3  7  9  8  23
```

Comment: this looks like a good solution too except that I would like to apply a logic to the '-2' entry . The logic should be that the number of rows is equal to the length of the column from the 'START' position to the end of the column. So in this case the resulting logic should be 2 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['jfgh',23,'Ndfg',34,0,56],'B':['jfgh',23,'START',34,0,56], 'C':['cvb',7,'dsfgA',65,47,3],'D':['rrb',7,'gfd',3,0,7],'E':['dfg',7,'gfd',5,12,1],'F':['dfg',7,'sdfA',5,0,4],'G':['dfg',7,'sdA',5,8,9],'H':['dfg',7,'gfA',5,0,8],'I':['dfg',7,'sdfA',5,7,23]})

for i, column in enumerate(df.columns):
    if df[column].str.startswith('START').sum() > 0:
        idx = i
        break
    
df.iloc[[-2, -1], [idx, idx+1, idx+2, -3, -2, -1]]
```

First find the column with the string that begins with "START" (by the way, if you are sure that the string not just starts with "START", but *is* "START", this can be simplified by directly using `==` instead of `.str.startswith`).

Then, as we know the index of first column, simly use `iloc`.

The problem with you solution, as I see, is that for whatever reason you hardcode the 'C' column and search "START" in it. You'd have to also iterate over columns, not just rows.

Comment: Hi Physmatik, thanks for this!! As a step further how would I 'generalise' the row indexing in `df.iloc[[-2, -1]`. In this case it was easy because we know its the last 2 rows. For the generalised case I attempted this `df.iloc[[i, len(df)], [idx, idx+1, idx+2, idx+5, idx+6, idx+7]]` It returned error `single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

Comment: How exactly you want to "generailize"? The most obvious way is to separately create an array with indices of all rows of interest, but depending on what you want there may be a neater way.